# How beautifulsoup objects able to have a tag as an attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Inorder to extract a tag, you need to use the tag as an attribute to the `Tag`/`BeautifulSoup` object, e.g. To extract the `<head>` tag, I need to do this `soupobject.head`

I'm still beginner in programming and python but from my understanding and quick google search, object attributes are variables belonging to that objects. I mean I can write a script that have a variable named `p` and have a condition that when my script run, if it find a `<p>` tag, it will then parse any relevant data from it and then assign it to the `p` variable I made, but to write a script that itself will "define" a variable and name it according to html tag name that I don't know how.

I hope I explaining it enough. I tried to understand the beautifulsoup source code but honestly I still having trouble understanding most of it.

My only assumption/theory on how it able to that, is by creating a string format of a python code then import that, I don't know if that possible

Comment: Could you provide some examples of what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [data model class customization via special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) and particularly at [customizing attribute access](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) via `__getattr__()` and `__getattribute__()` magic methods

In this particular case (`bs4`), you can have a look at bs4 source code for `Tag` class, where they define [`Tag.__getattr__()` magic method](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eleonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L1551). Note that [`BeautifulSoup` class inherits from `Tag`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eleonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/__init__.py#L75)

Also not that `soup.head` is not the only way to access `head` tag. you can do `soup.find('head')` - that is exactly what they do in `Tag.__getattr__()`.

To expand with an example

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.spam = 'spam'

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return f'Attribute "{name}" returned from __getattr__'

foo = Foo()
print(foo.spam)
print(foo.eggs)
```

output:

```
spam
Attribute "eggs" returned from __getattr__
```

Comment: I expanded my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not considered a good practice to have varaible variable names. Some languages even make it impossible to do so. In order to achieve the same thing, you can use a dictionary object which can have variable key-names and variable values.

```python
my_dict = {'key_1': 'value 1'}
print(my_dict['key_1'])
# out: 'value 1'

my_dict['some_key'] = 'another value'
# now your dictionary looks like this: 
# {'key_1': 'value 1', 'some_key': 'another value'}
print(my_dict['some_key'])
# out: 'another value'

# as for dynamic names:
some_name = 'key_3'
my_dict[some_name] = 'value 3'
print(my_dict)
# out: {'key_1': 'value 1', 'some_key': 'another value', 'key_3': 'value 3'}
```